# StringUtils for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Are there any StringUtils 'like' classes for working with the proprietary Salesforce.com Apex programming language?

**for example:**

`StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(String str1, String str2)`

`StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(String str1, String searchString)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, check [New String Methods](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Winter13/New+String+Methods) in Winter '13. Maybe this will avoid using third party utils/classes.

Comment: Awesome - Great to see more and more utilities make their way into the SFDC world!

Answer (score 2):

There's [apex-lang](http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/)'s [StringUtils](http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-project/src/classes/StringUtils.cls).

Comment: sweeeeeeeet :D - saves me a ton of time. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can download the basic implementation on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/MikeMcMahon/SFDC-StringUtils)!

The class above is open source and freely available for all to use; it currently provides only limited support for the following manipulations:

- isNotNullOrEmpty

  - returns true if the string is not null or is not empty
- isNullOrEmpty

  - returns true if the string is null or empty
- getSObjectField

  - pass in an sobject field and it will either return the value or an empty string if **null**
- equalsIgnoreCase

  - compares two strings ignoring case
- notEqualsIgnoreCase

  - compares two strings ignoring case and returns true if they are not equal
- contains

  - compares two strings and returns true if the first string contains the search string
- containsIgnoreCase

  - compares two strings (ignoring case) and returns true if the first string contains the search string

---

### StringUtils.cls

```
public class StringUtils {

    public static String getSObjectField(String str) { 
        if (str == null) { 
            return ''; 
        } 

        return str; 
    }

    public static Boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(String str) { 
        return !isNullOrEmpty(str); 
    }
    public static Boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
        // If the string is null  
        if (str == null) { 
            return true; 
        }

        // If the string contains only spaces
        String tmp = null; 
        tmp = str.replaceAll(' ', ''); 

        if (tmp.length() == 0) { 
            return true; 
        }

        return false; 
    }

    public static Boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2) { 
        // both strings must contain something
        if (str1 == null || str2 == null) { 
            return false;
        }

        // Use default functionality 
        return str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2); 
    }

    public static Boolean notEqualsIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2) { 
        return !equalsIgnoreCase(str1, str2); 
    }

    public static Boolean contains(String str, String searchStr) {
        // ensure the main string is not null 
        if (str == null) { 
            return false; 
        }

        // we actually have something to search for
        if (searchStr == null) { 
            return false;
        }

        // Search for it
        return str.contains(searchStr);          
    }

    public static Boolean containsIgnoreCase(String str, String searchStr) { 
        // ensure the main string is not null 
        if (str == null) { 
            return false; 
        }

        // we actually have something to search for
        if (searchStr == null) { 
            return false;
        }

        // Lowercase the str and searchStr and check it 
        return str.toLowerCase().contains(searchStr.toLowerCase()); 
    }
}
```